# Show that $S/(I\cap S)$ is isomorphic to $(I+S)/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $S$ be a subring of $R$. We know that

$I+S$ is a subring of $R$ containing $I$, and

$I\cap S$ is an ideal of $S$.

Without direct use of the first isomorphism theorem, I would like to show that $S/(I\cap S)$ is isomorphic to $(I+S)/I$.

So, first we need to define the homomorphism and then show that it is bijective. Would we define it as $\theta :S/(I\cap S) \to (I+S)/I$ and go from there? How would we show that it is onto and one-to-one?

Comment: Is there any reason for "without the first isomorphism theorem"? That's the easiest, almost trivial, and natural way to go, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio My book already does it through that method. My task is to do it this way. Is it really that much more difficult?

Comment: Even defining a homomorphism out of $S/(I\cap S)$ requires showing that the kernel of some (possibly implicitly defined) map out of $S$ contains $I \cap S$. Showing that it's injective ends up being equivalent to showing that the kernel is the all of $I \cap S$. So you'd end up using the isomorphism theorem, one way or another.

Comment: Hehe...I was about to write almost exactly what arkeet just wrote above. It's not a matter of difficulty but rather of futility: what for?!

Comment: If you want a variation from what the book does, try constructing the homomorphism going in the other direction.

Comment: @arkeet My professor did say that certain ideas from the first isomorphism theorem would be useful in defining the homomorphism but she was very hand wavy about it. Could you go into more detail about this method?

Answer (score 3):

Reinvent the wheel:

Define a map:
\begin{align}
S/I\cap S&\longrightarrow R/I\\
s+I\cap S&\longmapsto s+I
\end{align}

- This is well defined: if $s+I\cap S=t+I\cap S$, then *a fortiori*, $s+I=t+I$.
- It is trivial to check this is a morphism, and the image is $(S+I)/I$ by construction.
- It is injective: if $s+I=t+I$, $s-t\in I$. As it is also in $S$, it is indeed in $I\cap S$, so $s+I\cap S=t+I\cap S$.